# Arrange the arrayList in order in Android Application

Tags: android

I have the elements in Arraylist like

```
"Sowmya/20"
"Ramya/67"
"Archana/54"
"Kavitha/48"
.
.
.
```

Now I have to arrange these elements in descending order(by numbers) like

```
"Ramya/67"
"Archan/54"
"kavitha/48"
"Sowmya/20"
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick :

```
Collections.sort(myList, new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare (String s1, String s2) {
        int i1 = Integer.parseInt(s1.split("/")[1]);
        int i2 = Integer.parseInt(s2.split("/")[1]);
        return i1 - i2;
    }
});
```

Of course you will need to add some checks for production code (is there a slash in strings, is the second part always an integer, etc...)

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. but I need more clarification, Since I am new to this field.

Comment: ArrayList List1 = new ArrayList();
        List1.add("Sowmya/22");
        List1.add("Ramya/15");
        List1.add("Radhika/42");
        List1.add("Kavitha/81");
        List1.add("Komala/75");
        List1.add("Archana/51");
        List1.add("Shruthi/22");
        List1.add("Divya/46");
        Now I have to Sorted the List1. I get an error while using the above code. Pls help me

Comment: Sir, This is in ascending order. But for Descending order what we have to do? Pls tell me

Comment: For descending order, just returns i2-i1 instead

Comment: A bit of explanations : `s1.split("/")` creates an array of string elements splitted by '/'. `[1]` takes the second element, i.e. the substring behind the '/', which is a String representing a number. Then `Integer.parseInt()` converts a String to an integer, if it can... So: i1 is the integer for string s1, i2 is the integer for string s2. Now for the sorting, we use Collections.sort, which takes either a Collection of Comparable items, or a Collection, plus a Comparator. In this case we use an anonymous Comparator, whose compare function must return negative if s1 less than s2, 0 if equal...